# How to access to a struct parameter value from a variable in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to access to a struct properties with a variable who contains the property key.

For example, i got this struct :

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}
```

I have a variable "property" who contain a string value "age".

I would like to access to the age with something like **person.property** ?

Do you think it is possile in golang ?

Comment: It's possible with [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), but a very unusual requirement. If you tell us *why* you think you need this we can maybe show you a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for something like `person[property]` like you do in Python or JavaScript, the answer is NO, Golang does not support dynamic field/method selection at runtime.

But you can do it with `reflect`:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type person struct {
        name string
        age  int
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(person{"Golang", 10})
    property := "age"
    f := v.FieldByName(property)
    fmt.Printf("Person Age: %d\n", f.Int())
}
```